# Bind RET to send scheme code in emacs

Tags: emacs, scheme, elisp

I want to set up my `.emacs` so that when I am in my `*scheme*` buffer I can bind `RET` to `C-x C-e` (because I use `C-j` for newlines). I get to the scheme buffer like this:

`M-x load-library RET xscheme RET` note - how can I automate that step?

`M-x run-scheme`

Here's what I tried, it doesn't work:

```
(eval-after-load 'xscheme
                 '(define-key scheme-mode-map 
                              (kbd "RET") 
                              'advertised-xscheme-send-previous-expression))
```

Comment: I believe emacs questions are still on-topic on SO, but just FYI, there *is* now an [Emacs.SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AlexisKing If you think it's better, feel free to migrate it. I posted on SO because I figured there would be more people knowledgeable about scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange to bind it like that.
Here's how it's done in Emacs 24.4:

```
(eval-after-load 'cmuscheme
  (define-key inferior-scheme-mode-map
      (kbd "RET") 'scheme-send-last-sexp))
```

Comment: Why cmuscheme? The library is xscheme.

Comment: That's where `run-scheme` is defined in the current Emacs 24.4

Comment: Ya, but I load xscheme before running run-scheme. Does that change anything?